# RDF java sample of freebase not working

Tags: java, rdf, freebase, n3

https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/rdf-overview.

The java code gives the following error. Please let me know how to resolve this.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 190, col: 37] illegal escape sequence value: x (0x78)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorHandlerStd.fatal(ErrorHandlerFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.raiseException(LangEngine.java:169)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.nextToken(LangEngine.java:116)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.predicateObjectItem(LangTurtleBase.java:299)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.predicateObjectList(LangTurtleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triples(LangTurtleBase.java:271)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triplesSameSubject(LangTurtleBase.java:210)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtle.oneTopLevelElement(LangTurtle.java:47)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.runParser(LangTurtleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangBase.parse(LangBase.java:42)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTFactoryImpl$1.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:142)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:760)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:258)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:244)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.RDFReaderRIOT.read(RDFReaderRIOT.java:69)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:274)
    at holidayplanner.freebase.sample.RdfSample.main(RdfSample.java:32)
```

Comment: What is the query you used? The exception says " illegal escape sequence value: x" at [line: 190, col: 37]

Comment: Additionally you can configure log4j in about 2.2 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Did you look at the data on line 190 of https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/rdf/m/02h40lc ?

```
ns:common.topic.alias    "Ingl\xeas"@pt;
```

It's not valid N3. http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/n3/#escaping

You'll need to pre-process the data into a valid form if you want RDF parsers to be able to deal with it. (And, of course, you should report the bug to Google as well).

Comment: This came up on Twitter recently when I was asked to pronounce if it was valid Turtle (NO) and Google folks are aware of it (danbri)

Comment: Escaping doesn't see to be helping. To start with all '\x' i replace with \\x.  It however started giving org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 217, col: 623] Triples not terminated by DOT.

Comment: Is there a utility which i can use to escape the characters in RDF file in java?

Comment: The standard calls for Unicode codepoints escape as \uNNNN.  You'll need to decode the \xnn escapes into binary which should give you UTF-8 strings that you can then convert to Unicode codepoints and output them with the appropriate escaping.